# Checking the equivalence of conditional expectations

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X,X^1,\dots,X^{k-1},X^k\in\mathbb{R}$ be random variables, and let us define the conditional expectations as
$$
f_{k-1}=\mathbb{E}[X|X^1,\dots,X^{k-1}]; \quad
f_k=\mathbb{E}[X|X^1,\dots,X^k].
$$
Is it true that
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[f_k\,|\,X^1,\dots,X^{k-1}]f_k\Big]
=\mathbb{E}[f_kf_k].
$$
My attempt:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[f_k\,|\,X^1,\dots,X^{k-1}]f_k\Big]
&=\mathbb{E}\bigg[\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[f_k|X^1,\dots,X^{k-1}]f_k\Big|X^k\Big]\bigg] \\
&=\mathbb{E}\bigg[\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[1|X^1,\dots,X^{k-1}]f_kf_k\Big|X^k\Big]\bigg] \\
&=\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[f_kf_k|X^k]\Big]
=\mathbb{E}[f_kf_k].
\end{align*}
Is this correct? If not, then where did my logic break? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your identity is correct?  I suspect the right hand side of your proposed identity is $E[f_{k - 1}f_k]$.

Comment: Yes it is what I want, in other words, I want to show that $\mathbb{E}[f_{k-1}f_k]=\mathbb{E}[f_{k}f_k]$

Comment: Is that possible?

Comment: I am inclined to not possible.  Your second equality is baseless -- $f_k$ is not $\sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_{k - 1})$-measurable so I don't know how you took $f_k$ out from the inner-most conditional expectation.  On the other hand, because $\{f_k\}$ is a martingale with respect to $\{X_1, \ldots, X_k\}$, the equality $E[f_kf_{k - 1}] = E[f_{k - 1}^2]$ is correct.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Can you please provide a full answer below for how you obtain $E[f_kf_{k-1}]=E[f_{k-1}^2]$. It will be very helpful to me, thanks. I'll most definitely accept it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the identity should be (to avoid confusing your notation "$X^k$" with the conventional exponent notation, I will use $X_k$ instead in my answer below):
\begin{align*}
E[E[f_k|X_1, \ldots, X_{k - 1}]f_k] = E[f_{k - 1}^2]. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}

To show $\eqref{1}$, we first show that $\{f_k\}$ is a martingale with respect to the natural filtration $\mathscr{F}_k = \sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_k)$, i.e., $E[f_k|X_1, \ldots, X_{k - 1}] = f_{k - 1}$, which follows directly from the tower property of conditional expectation:
\begin{align*}
 & E[f_k|X_1, \ldots, X_{k - 1}] \\
=& E[E[X|X_1, \ldots, X_k]|X_1, \ldots, X_{k - 1}] \\
=& E[X|X_1, \ldots, X_{k - 1}] \\
=& f_{k - 1}. 
\end{align*}

Hence $\eqref{1}$ is equivalent to $E[f_kf_{k - 1}] = E[f_{k - 1}^2]$.  To show this identity, apply the law of iterative expectations and the martingale property just proved:
\begin{align*}
 & E[f_kf_{k - 1}] \\
=& E[E[f_kf_{k - 1}|\mathscr{F}_{k - 1}]] \tag{2}\label{2} \\
=& E[f_{k - 1}E[f_k|\mathscr{F}_{k - 1}]] \tag{3}\label{3} \\
=& E[f_{k - 1}f_{k - 1}] \\
=& E[f_{k - 1}^2]. 
\end{align*}
From $\eqref{2}$ to $\eqref{3}$, $f_{k - 1}$ can be pulled out from the inner conditional expectation because it is $\mathscr{F}_{k - 1}$-measurable by definition.  This completes the proof.

Comment: That makes sense to me, thank you so much.